# Is this Technique correct?

Tags: number-theory

Statement: If every sufficiently large integer $N$ $=$ $p$ $+$ $n$ where $p$ is prime dividing $4n^2$ $+$ $1$, then there can only be finitely many primes of the form $x^2$ $+$ $1$.

Here's the proof technique:

By the first supplement to the Quadratic Reciprocity theorem we are assured that the primes dividing $x^2$ $+$ $1$ must be of the form $4a$ $+$ $1$. Then for a prime $p$ dividing some $X^2$ $+$ $1$, one can easily generate the set of all $X_i$ such that $p$ divides $X_i^2$ $+$ $1$ and $X_i$ can be expressed as $p+n$ where $p$ divides $4n^2 + 1$. This means that if $X_n^2 + 1$ is prime, $X_n$ does not belong to any of the set. So if we assume there are only finitely many primes of the form $X^2$ $+$ $1$, every sufficiently large integer $N$ must belong to the set generated by some prime say $q$ and thus expressible as a $q+m$ where $q$ divides $4m^2 + 1$.

This is just a flow and might be not understandable. I just want to know if the Technique is correct.

Comment: In the last part, it is assumed that only finite many numbers $x^2+1$ are prime, which has to be proven. To prove the statement, better assume that there are infinite many primes of the form $x^2+1$ and disproof the first part of the statement.

Comment: Must the number $N$ be even or can it also be odd ?

Comment: I assumed there are only finitely many prime number $x^2 + 1$ so that if not every large number $N$ can be expressed as $p+n$, then indeed there are infinitely may primes $x^2 + 1$. the number $N$ can be odd or even.

Comment: I strongly believe that not every large integer $N$ is so expressible as $p+n$, meaning there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2 + 1$ but I just cannot prove it. One attack I used to try to prove that not all large $N$  can be expressed as $p+n$ is that, if $N=p+n$, then $N^a = q+m$ and so $(p+n)^a=q+n$ for all integer $a$ greater than 1.

Comment: the last part $(p+n)^a=q+m$

Comment: the $q$ above is prime dividing $4m^2 + 1$

Comment: The statement is not an equivalence. Even if not every sufficiently large $N$ is expressible in the given way, the number of primes of the form $x^2+1$ might be finite. The statement does not tell anything in the case that not every sufficiently large $N$ is expressible in the given way.

Comment: Another fact is that for primes $p$. If every large $N=p_i+n_i$, then, $(p_1+n_1)(p_2+n_2)(p_3+n_3)...$ can always be written as $p_a +n_a$, which again "seems" impossible. $p_n$ does not mean the nth prime number.

Comment: The converse of my statement holds. I've reviewed my result many times

Comment: In thic case, you should formulate it with "if and only if".

Comment: There can only be finite primes $x^2 + 1$ iff every large integer belong to the "SET" I mentioned above , meaning if there exist a prime $q$ that generated that large integer.

Comment: ...and every element in the set generated by the prime $q$ can always be expressed as $q+m$ where again $q$ divides $4m^2 + 1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30192/discussion-between-jevie-and-peter).

Comment: OK, first lets delete most of the comments.